# Issue when trying to sort array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```
        // const first = data.groups_with_selected[7];
        // const second = data.groups_with_selected[20];
        // data.groups_with_selected.splice(2, 0, first, second);
        // data.groups_with_selected.splice(9, 1)
        // data.groups_with_selected.splice(21, 1)
```

But Issue with the above code is that, I am able to get the updated **sorted console** value in the console. But filters wise it's not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution for this problem is by grouping the array first, then use `flat()` to flatten/restore it so it have the same level:

```js
const orderMap = ['third', 'second', 'first'];

const array = [{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}, {name: 'third'}, {name: 'second'}];

const sorted = orderMap.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
prev[index] = array.filter(item => item.name === curr)
return prev
}, []).flat()

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Thanks, if possible Can you please give some clarity on how to utilize same thing with my api response. like how can i group array first by name.

Comment: I think flat() required here, because after changes i want it to be standard so...

Comment: first, the `orderMap` should be correct, i suggest you that `orderMap` is provided from the api as well. then you can use `computed` in vue to compute the sorted output

Comment: Thanks. const orderMap = ['third', 'second', 'first'];
const array = [{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}, {name: 'third'}];

in this two lines of my code, How can i take orderMap , array(based on my example please give some idea)

Comment: i am getting response from data.groups_with_selected   (followed by for [7].name)

Comment: if your expectation is `i want to change (7th position to 2nd position)(21st position to 3rd position)`. theo nly solution is either you write `orderMap` manually, or you ask your backend to provide it based on your need.

Comment: or you extract the `name` to be a one level array for `orderMap` then shuffle the order as you need. but I can't revise my answer at the moment